# Differences in capability between cross-cut, plunge, and traditional circular saws?

Tags: tools, powertools, circular-saw

I just purchased a new house that needs a lot of work. I'm looking to purchase my first circular saw. I'm in Europe and like Mafell, but I'm struggling to understand the trade-offs between their:

- [cross-cut saw](http://katalog.mafell.de/index.php?IdTreeGroup=12962&IdProduct=24837)
- [plunge-cut saw](http://katalog.mafell.de/index.php?IdTreeGroup=12968&IdProduct=31522)
- [circular saw](http://katalog.mafell.de/index.php?IdTreeGroup=12961&IdProduct=31507)

They all seem to allow for plunge cuts. They all seem to allow for cross-cuts given the guide rails. What other significant differences in capability to they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you can do plunge cuts with all of them. The plunge cut saw is designed for more precise control of depth and position of such cuts. It's really more of an industry specialty tool.

It's not clear to me what the differences are between the cross cut and circular saws. I would have a look at them in person and see what features they each have. It appears that one of them may have an exhaust port designed to connect a vacuum. It may therefore be more expensive due to features that you don't need.

Nearly all professional carpenters as well as homeowners in my area used basic circular saws. Try to find one with smooth, quiet bearings and a good reputation for quality. If you need to cut cement board siding, purchase one with sealed bearings. If conversation is important, look for one with the automatic brake, which stops the blade fairly quickly after a cut.

Comment: In the link above, the "cross cut" saw has a large metal plate attached to it. I don't speak German, but there are more pictures in the linked PDF. It looks like you're supposed to clamp the big plate to the wood, and then the saw slides along a rail, keeping the cut straight. Could be very useful in some cases, but I wouldn't buy it as a general-purpose saw.

Comment: You can change the site to English with the flag at the bottom of the page.